# Is there a markup language underlying MS Word and Libre Office?

Tags: xml, ms-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm curious about the backend for WYSIWYG editors (specifically librewriter and MS Word).

I know that you can produce fancy and nicely typeset documents using LaTeX, TeX and HTML+CSS. I was wondering if any of these markup languages (or something similar) underlies popular word processing software packages?

Answer (score 1):

Both MS Office and Open/Libre Office use XML for the stored document representation format (see http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm for MSO and https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office for Open/Libre Office; some of the specs have been republished as ISO standards). Basically, a .docx file is a ZIP archive containing XML files. Though neither of these office suites, being WYSIWYG-era software, started with a markup-based format as native storage format. Well-known text processors based natively on markup/plain text are WordPerfect and IBM SCRIPT/VS (the latter one introducing GML which later was extended to SGML and forming the base for both HTML and XML).

Answer (score 0):

The markup language used by MS Word's DOCX format is covered by [Standard ECMA-376
Office Open XML File Formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm), aka OOXML.  Libre Office can also import and export DOCX.

**See also:**

- [Where can I find the XSDs of DOCX XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36428294/290085)
- [XML/XSD validation for a Word doc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801066/290085)
- [Microsoft Word (OOXML/DOCX) documents formatting validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53581421/290085)
- [Eric White's Open XML blog](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several sites with useful information about the OOXML file format. [OfficeOpenXML](http://officeopenxml.com/) has the most verbose explanations of OOXML. Other sites, like datypic.com and [c-rex.net](https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/Intro/about.html) are mostly repackagings of the ECMA specs in a more readable form. I write about OOXML from the point of view of useful techniques for common Office problems: [OOXML Hacking: Locking Graphics](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/09/xml-hacking-locking-graphics/)